# Removing bodies from joints in Chipmunk Physics

Tags: physics, chipmunk

In Box2D, when a body that is connected to a joint is removed from the space, the joint is automatically deleted and you can do stuff in callbacks and so on.

Does Chipmunk do this? If so, how can I detect when a joint connection is 'broken'? Do I have to keep track of this stuff manually?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by detecting when a joint is broken.  I don't believe Chipmunk breaks joints as part of the simulation.  If the joint is broken because a body has been destroyed be careful on cleanup. From the documentation page for Chipmunk:

> Be careful not to free a body before any shapes or constraints attached to it have been removed from a space.

Use cpSpaceRemoveConstraint and it will remove it from both bodies.  Then free the constraint memory using cpConstraintFree.